# How run android (USB) in API localhost (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: android, laravel, api, ionic-framework, usb

I have a APIs in Laravel in localhost and with ionic runing android device with USB
but a get this error http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

How can I access my Api in my localhost with ionic run android -l ?

Comment: Your Android device is its own localhost. Is Laravel running on your Android phone?

Comment: no, Laravel run in my PC

Comment: I connected USB in device and run the following command "ionic cordova run android -l"

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the laravel app runing on your computer IP `192.168.1.9` then request the api via this ip
Or another way use ngrok it might help you

Comment: so, Laravel is runing in my PC, when I test the APIs working fine in POSTMAN to this IP

Comment: Let me explain it more, When you run ```php artisan serve``` the laravel start a server on your PC Localhost and when you test it using postman (which is running on the same PC laravel is starting on) it works fine but when you go to your ionc app you try to request the localhost of the android phone (whichh laravel is not running on ) so you got an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to run laravel using your ip address so that your phone can be able to access your computer.
Serve your app using this command

```
php artisan serve --host your_ip_address
```

Then access your laravel backend using the url below

```
http://your_ip_address:8000
```

Replace 'your_ip_address' with you actual ip address e.g

```
192.168.43.204
```